# compare contents of two text files in ubuntu?

Tags: text-processing, diff

I need to compare the contents of text files (as a whole and not line-wise like diff command) and print out the missing text. Is there a command to do so? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As an example, say file1 has:

```
1 2 3
4 5
```

file 2 has got:

```
1 5
2 3 4 6
```

I want to compare these files and print as output:

```
6
```

The command `diff` compares the text files line by line, in which case, almost the entire file will be printed out. (My actual files are more complicated and lengthy, so I'm giving a simple example.)

Comment: Post an example of what you want to achieve, please.

Comment: @muru I edited the question. Could you please check now and let me know  a plausible solution.

Comment: Your example does not make sense. In file 2, `5`'s relative location was changed, so why isn't it counted in changes? If you compare the text "as a whole", `5`'s location changes. Please specify your actual criteria for changes.

Comment: I only want to know the extra content that is missing in one of the files when compared with the other, irrespective of the location changes of the content.  The location changes have to be ignored and only the contents have to be compared and print out the missing text . ( My contents in actual file are words separated by spaces.)

Comment: And if the input was `1 3 2`, `4 3 5`, which `3` is extra?

Comment: I think `3` and `4` should be extras...IMO

Comment: @muru As I'm looking only for the extra content, depending on the what the other file has, ( if it has only a single 3 ) either of the two 3's will do.

Answer (score 4):

Since the order does not matter, you can use awk for printing unique lines, but with whitespace separating lines:

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} {a[$0]--} END {for (i in a) if (a[i] != 0) print i}' file1 file2
```

Here:

- `-v RS='[[:space:]]+'` sets the record separator (RS) to any whitespace, so all each "line" will be separated by any whitespace (including newlines).
- `FNR == NR` - `FNR` is the record number (`NR`) (or, line number, if you will) for the current file, and `NR` is the overall line number in all input files. So, whenever these two are equal, we're dealing with the first file.
- `{a[$0]++; next}` - set and increment the count of appearances of the current "line", then move to the next line without processing any more rules. This block is only run for the first file, so the effect is that this rule applies to lines from the first file, and the next block applies to to all other files.
- `{a[$0]--}`, decrement the count of appearances of the current "line".
- `END {for (i in a) if (a[i] != 0) print i}` - at the END of all input, for each entry in the array `a`, print that entry if the count of appearances is not 0. So, any "line" which was seen an equal number of times in both files will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution:

```
comm -3 <( cat file1 | tr ' \t' '\n' | sort) <(cat file2 | tr ' \t' '\n' | sort) | sort -u
```

where:

- `tr ' \t' '\n' | sort` replace space and tab with newline, and reorder the result
- `comm` Compares sorted files `file1` and `file2` line by line, and with `-3` option suppress lines that appear in both files
- `sort -u` at last, removes duplicate lines, this is necessary in case of duplicate token

In this case `tr ' ' '\n' | sort` output is used as standard input for `comm` command.

Comment: You should use `sort -u` to avoid issues with multiple entries

Comment: +1; I'd do it with `sed 's/ /\n/g' file1` to avoid `cat` and `pipe`, but imho this is the best solution. Why is it printed `\t6` ?

Comment: I meant `sort -u` inside the `<()`

Comment: If you put sort -u inside, you did not detect duplicate tokes, as I understand OP would like to get it. For example: file1 = 1 3 1 4 5 and file2 = 5 1 4 3 6, expected output: 1 6. You suggestion was right, because without last sort the output would be 1 1 6.

Comment: @RoVo thanks again, I update my answer and add \t substitution

Comment: @samhitha, A single '6' is what you want as output from the input in your original question. What output would you want from the example in Lety's comment? '1 and 6' or only '6'?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the following: Your files consist of data, that are either separated with a space or newline AND you do not care about knowing where the data is missing (or know it is always e.g. in file2).

What we will do is simple:
Replace every space with a newline in both files, concatenate them, then search for single (unique) entries only:

```
sort <( tr ' ' '\n' < file1 ) <(tr ' ' '\n' < file2) | uniq -u
```

Comment: did you try this? doesn't work

Comment: @RoVo  - Updated and tested. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

### Preparation of the files

If I understand correctly, you want to print unique numbers or words in the comparison. I would convert the files so that each number/word has an own line, sort them, remove blank lines and duplicates and after that compare the files.

I assume that space characters are separating the numbers or words. For each file

```
< file-x.orig tr ' ' '\n' | tr -s '\n' '\n' |sort -u > file-x.1
```

See `man tr` for details.

If you want to sort numerically, you can add the option `-n` or `-h` depending of the numeric format. See `man sort` for details.

### The example of your original question,

In the example of the original question, I would use `-n`,

```
< file-x.orig tr ' ' '\n' | tr -s '\n' '\n' |sort -nu > file-x.1
```

where x can be a and b for the two files to compare, so for example

```
< file-a.orig tr ' ' '\n' | tr -s '\n' '\n' |sort -nu > file-a.1
< file-b.orig tr ' ' '\n' | tr -s '\n' '\n' |sort -nu > file-b.1
```

You can inspect these converted and sorted files, if you wish.

Finally compare the files with the following command line,

```
$ diff file-a.1 file-b.1
5a6
> 6
```

This identifies the number, that is only found in the second file of your sample input from the original question. See `man diff` for details, if you want a modified output from `diff`.

### My example

This is an example with a unique number in each of the files.

```
$ echo '1 2 3 4 5'>file-c.orig
$ echo '2 3 4 5 6'>file-d.orig
$ < file-c.orig tr ' ' '\n' | tr -s '\n' '\n' |sort -nu > file-c.1
$ < file-d.orig tr ' ' '\n' | tr -s '\n' '\n' |sort -nu > file-d.1
$ diff  file-c.1 file-d.1
1d0
< 1
5a5
> 6
```

This identifies

- '1' that is only found in the 1st file, indicated by '<'
- '6' that is only found in the 2nd file, indicated by '>'

### The example in Lety's comment

> For example: file1 = 1 3 1 4 5 and file2 = 5 1 4 3 6, expected output: 1 6.

```
$ echo '1 3 1 4 5'>file-e.orig
$ echo '5 1 4 3 6'>file-f.orig

$ < file-e.orig tr ' ' '\n' | tr -s '\n' '\n' |sort -nu > file-e.1
$ < file-f.orig tr ' ' '\n' | tr -s '\n' '\n' |sort -nu > file-f.1
$ diff  file-e.1 file-f.14a5
> 6

$ comm -3 <( cat file-e.orig | tr ' \t' '\n' | sort) <(cat file-f.orig | tr ' \t' '\n' | sort) | sort -u
1
    6

$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} {a[$0]--} END {for (i in a) if (a[i] != 0) print i}' file-e.orig file-f.orig
1
6
```

In this case my method shows a different result compared to the methods of @Lety and @muru. Let us wait for the OP, @samhitha, to tell us what is the desired output of the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (python):

```
def readFile(fi):
  return open(fi,"rb").read().decode(cod)
def process(text):
  return text.replace("\n"," ").split(" ")

print(set([x for x in process(readFile(file1,"utf-8")) if not x==""]).difference(set([x for x in process(readFile(file2,"utf-8")) if not x==""])))
```